# Client wants to remove footer on certain pages, should I?

Tags: gui-design

I have a client who insists that we remove the footer from certain pages under the guise of 'the footer will distract people and they will leave the site/not finish the journey'.

To me, this sounds unfounded. If people want to leave the site they will. Removing the footer will not stop that, nor are people that easily distracted.

However, my colleagues advise me that at the end of the day it's the clients website and we should do as they ask. I understand this, "the customer is always right" logic being applied.

But in my honest opinion, I don't think the customer is right and could do with advice from myself or my colleagues regarding this matter.

I wanted to pose the question here to see how important a footer is in for user experience? All the research I've done suggests it's relatively important and while most of the articles I've read suggest to do at least something with it, none have suggested to remove it entirely.

The clients footer contains links to terms and conditions, how the site works, other related websites which are theirs and a few documents.

Comment: One what pages is the client suggesting the footer be removed? If, for example, it is during a checkout process it... SQUIRREL!

Comment: ... might be appropriate to help keep the customer engaged in the process. But removing it from other places is certainly less advantageous.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main questions here. The first is: "Is the footer important." There are some things that ought to be on every page - copyright and legal disclaimers are two. If the client has a footer in his email then that might be a segue into convincing him that the footer on the website has validity and ought to remain.

> Jakob Nielsen wrote: "As another example, fat footers can greatly
>   increase usability for people who arrive at the end of a page without
>   finding what they want. Fat footers also strengthen structural SEO by
>   guiding link juice to the site's best pages about each key topic. All
>   for the good; in fact, fat footers have now become so common that
>   we've moved our discussion of them from our Emerging Patterns for Web
>   Design course to our seminar on proven best practices for Web Page
>   Design." http://www.nngroup.com/articles/seo-and-usability/

Regarding the issue of the "client is always right". I solve that problem by bringing up my objections and then, after making the appropriate defense of the position, I wash my hands of it. You can only push a point for so long. Bring it up in a meeting, send emails to the appropriate individuals, if you are overruled - you are overruled.

Comment: I like Jakob Nielsen, I really do, but SEO has it that on many sites footer links will be marked as `rel=nofollow`. Footers also add visual noise that is not always justified. It really depends! Anyhow, really agree with the attitude on the last paragraph; well put.

Comment: It depends on the site. On some it's more appropriate than others. For instance on single page sites - those with the hero shots and scrolling from one section to the next, on those sites the footer is almost never seen. But ultimately the footer (for legal reasons if nothing else) is almost always advisable.

Answer (score 1):

> To me, this sounds unfounded. If people want to leave the site they will. Removing the footer will not stop that, nor are people that easily distracted.

**Yes, totally unfounded.**

It *might* make sense to remove the footer. You won't have a real answer beyond a guess until you run it by a few users. Then at least you will have evidence one way or another. It would help your customer service showing that you took the initiative to dig deeper. Its hard to argue real data.

It seems that the footer needs additional thought if its a distraction at all. In general (and in a perfect world), remove anything from the screen that is not absolutely necessary.

Dig a little deeper and it will make the client/designer debate more constructive.